# Atmel studio 7 - my own libraries

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-ide, atmel-studio

I like to use AS7 to make my programs. 
I know c and some c++, but how things work from there I'm green.
I would like to know if there is a folder where I can store my own homemade c and h library files where they get to be available for all my projects.
Now I copy all the files into each of my projects and this works but I find it a bit tedious.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your library as a separate project: File->New->Project and select C or C++ static library:

[image: creating c++ static library]

Add your library modules in this project. When building, this will create **lib{your_project_name}.a** file (in Debug or Release folder) - your library object file you can use in your other projects.

Usually I include in the same solution both the library project and target project (just library project file, sure the library and it's files resides in single place):

[image: project solution]

**ORDO** is the library name.

Some check list:

- Include the library file in Libraries folder (shown above)
- Specify the path to the library *.a file for linker (Toolchain->AVR/GNU Linker->Libraries). Note that there should be different paths for Debug and Release configurations.
- Specify the path for library include files (Toolchain->AVR/GNU C or C++ Compiler->Directories)
- In some cases, F_CPU definition might be needed for library project too (same as in your project, under Symbols).
- When changes are made in your library files, use Build solution (F7) when building, if not - you can use Build project (which will be faster).

Setting project dependencies shall also lead to rebuilding the library automatically when needed (not tested, I usually just hit F7 :).

Comment: Thank you for a good answer, I belive i see where to begin now. just as to what to do next, lets say you wanted to make a reusable library for those ds18B20 sensors I see you got there... I have googled around trying to find out how to do this but I cant seem to find any that enlighten me.

Comment: I used library from Davide Gironi: http://davidegironi.blogspot.com/2014/09/a-ds18b20-1-wire-digital-thermometer.html - it has no external onewire module, it is basic, minimalistic, doesn't support bus enumeration etc but might be good starting point to implement own.

Comment: Nice idea, but what if my own library has Arduino dependencies? I get stuck at this point, because of course requires the Arduino core stuff

Comment: Please check [AS7 + Arduino + Libraries: How?!](http://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/1939591#comment-1939591) and [Tutorial: Using Atmel Studio 6 with Arduino projects](http://www.engblaze.com/tutorial-using-atmel-studio-6-with-arduino-projects/)